# how to write batch script file to install Tomcat and other

Tags: tomcat, batch-file

Hai to all,

Please let me fly on top ,

I really strucked up at creating a batch file , which installs Tomcat and my java exe application and copy some files to the specified directory and it has to close automatically.

thanks in advance .

Comment: It is not clear what you want. Can you be more specific?

Answer (score 1):

Java and Tomcat can both be run without being installed.  Zip them up in an appropriate folder structure and bundle your batch file with the zip.  Uninstall it at the appropriate place on the user's computer.  You may need to alter catalina.sh to point to the Java directory.